# How to pass an array in view to ajax and accessible in controller for Laravel 5?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel-5, post

I am trying to pass an array of data in a table in my blade view to my controller using AJAX. I am able to return a response when i click the save button but the sets of array data are ignored. I guess the array data are not passed successfully because I do not know the right way to do it.

I have tried declaring an array variable and store the sets of array data but still nothing happens.

BLADE

```
@foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
  @if ($d->particular <> 'Outcome Indicators' && $d->particular <> 'Output Indicators')
        <tr id="headerhep1{{ $d->id }}">
        <td rowspan="1" class="item_part text-blue">{{ $d->particular }} <input type="text" name="hep1part[]" id="hep1part[]" value="{{ $d->id }}" hidden></td>
        <td class="item_uacs text-teal"></td>
        <td contenteditable="false" class="item_ptq1{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pt1[]" id="hep1pt1[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PT1 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_ptq2{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pt2[]" id="hep1pt2[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PT2 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_ptq3{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pt3[]" id="hep1pt3[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PT3 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_ptq4{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pt4[]" id="hep1pt4[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PT4 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_pttot{{ $d->id }} text-green"><textarea name="hep1pt5[]" id="hep1pt5[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PT5 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_paq1{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pa1[]" id="hep1pa1[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PA1 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_paq2{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pa2[]" id="hep1pa2[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PA2 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_paq3{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pa3[]" id="hep1pa3[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PA3 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_paq4{{ $d->id }} text-red"><textarea name="hep1pa4[]" id="hep1pa4[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PA4 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_patot{{ $d->id }} text-green"><textarea name="hep1pa5[]" id="hep1pa5[]" cols="4" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->PA5 }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_var{{ $d->id }} text-blue"><textarea name="hep1var[]" id="hep1var[]" cols="6" rows="2" maxlenght="20" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->variance }}</textarea></td>
        <td class="item_rem{{ $d->id }} text-orange"><textarea name="hep1rem[]" id="hep1rem[]" cols="27" rows="3" maxlenght="60" style="overflow:hidden;resize:none;text-align: center;border:0px;background-color: transparent;">{{ $d->remarks }}</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      @else
      <tr id="headerhep1{{ $d->id }}">
        <td rowspan="1" class="item_part text-blue">{{ $d->particular }}</td>
        <td class="item_uacs text-teal"></td>
        <td class="item_ptq1{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_ptq2{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_ptq3{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_ptq4{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_pttot{{ $d->id }} text-green"></td>
        <td class="item_paq1{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_paq2{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_paq3{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_paq4{{ $d->id }} text-red"></td>
        <td class="item_patot{{ $d->id }} text-green"></td>
        <td class="item_var{{ $d->id }} text-blue"></td>
        <td class="item_rem{{ $d->id }} text-orange"></td>
      </tr>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
  $('.save_hep1').on('click','.hep1_save', function(){
      if ($('h4[name=ifsu_user_role]').text()  == 'Guest')
      {
        alert('Guest users are not allowed to this function.');
        return false;
      }
      else{
    $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
    var hep1part = [];
    var hep1pt1 = [];
    var hep1pt2 = [];
    var hep1pt3 = [];
    var hep1pt4 = [];
    var hep1pt5 = [];
    var hep1pa1 = [];
    var hep1pa2 = [];
    var hep1pa3 = [];
    var hep1pa4 = [];
    var hep1pa5 = [];
    var hep1var = [];
    var hep1rem = [];
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: './editItem_hep1',
          data: {
              '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
              'hep1part': [$("#hep1part").text()],
              'hep1pt1': [$("#hep1pt1").text()],
              'hep1pt2': [$("#hep1pt2").text()],
              'hep1pt3': [$("#hep1pt3").text()],
              'hep1pt4': [$("#hep1pt4").text()],
              'hep1pt5': [$("#hep1pt5").text()],
              'hep1pa1': [$("#hep1pa1").text()],
              'hep1pa2': [$("#hep1pa2").text()],
              'hep1pa3': [$("#hep1pa3").text()],
              'hep1pa4': [$("#hep1pa4").text()],
              'hep1pa5': [$("#hep1pa5").text()],
              'hep1var': [$("#hep1var").text()],
              'hep1rem': [$("#hep1rem").text()]
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');
                if ((data.errors)) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#editModalEnroll').modal('show');
                        toastr.error('Validation error!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 3000});
                    }, 500);
                    if (data.errors.title) {
                        $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                    }
                    if (data.errors.content) {
                        $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                    }
                }
                else if ((data.msg)) 
                {
                   $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                  toastr.warning('Record not found! Record might has been deleted earlier or has been altered.', 'Oops Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                    $('.items' + id).remove();
                    $('.form-horizontal').show();
                }
                else if (data.exmsg){
                  toastr.warning('Something went wrong.', 'Oops Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                  $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                }
                 else {
                    toastr.success('Successfully updated this record!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});

                    $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                }
            },
            statusCode: {
            401: function() { 
                window.location.href = 'login'; //or what ever is your login URI 
              }
            }
        });
      }
    });
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
Public function editItem_hep1(Request $r)
{
    $barnumberedit = 12;

    try
    {
    if ($qprbars = QprBarHEP1Value::where('qpr_bar_id','=',$barnumberedit)
        ->count() <= 0 or $qprbars = QprBarAEPValue::where('qpr_bar_id','=',$barnumberedit)
        ->count() <= 0)
    {
        return response()->json(['danger' => true, 'created'=> true, 'msg' => 'Some program particulars are missing. Please generate before you can save changes. Update aborted.']);
    }else
    {
        foreach ($r->hep1part as $key => $v)
        {
            $data = array(
              'qpr_bar_id'=>12,
              'PT1'=>$r->hep1pt1[$key],
              'PT2'=>$r->hep1pt2[$key],
              'PT3'=>$r->hep1pt3[$key],
              'PT4'=>$r->hep1pt4[$key],
              'PT5'=>$r->hep1pt5[$key],
              'PA1'=>$r->hep1pa1[$key],
              'PA2'=>$r->hep1pa2[$key],
              'PA3'=>$r->hep1pa3[$key],
              'PA4'=>$r->hep1pa4[$key],
              'PA5'=>$r->hep1pa5[$key],
              'variance'=>$r->hep1var[$key],
              'remarks'=>$r->hep1rem[$key],
              'updated_user_id'=>Auth::user()->id
            );
            QprBarHEP1Value::where('qpr_bar_id','=', $barnumberedit)->where('id','=',$v)->update($data);
            return response()->json($data);
        }
        return back()->with('success','Program particulars updated successfully.');
    }
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'created'=> true, 'exmsg' => 'Sorry something went wrong.']);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the wrong IDs. `$("#hep1part").text()` should be `$("#hep1part[]").text()`, that's how you name it (didn't look the rest of the code).

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it how. I do not know if this kind of approach is correct but it's working.

```
@if (count($qprbar1_hep1))
    <script>
      //HEP
      $('.save_hep1').on('click','.hep1_save', function(){
          if ($('h4[name=ifsu_user_role]').text()  == 'Guest')
          {
            alert('Guest users are not allowed to this function.');
            return false;
          }
          else{
        $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
            var hep1part = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                "{{ $d->id }}", 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pt1 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pt1{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pt2 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pt2{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pt3 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pt3{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pt4 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pt4{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pt5 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pt5{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pa1 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pa1{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pa2 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pa2{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pa3 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pa3{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pa4 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pa4{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1pa5 = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1pa5{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1var = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1var{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            var hep1rem = [
            @foreach ($qprbar1_hep1 as $d)
                $("#hep1rem{{ $d->id }}").val(), 
            @endforeach
            ];
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: './editItem_hep1',
              data: {
                  '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                  'bar_rec_id': $("#barnumberedit").val(),
                  'hep1part': hep1part,
                  'hep1pt1':  hep1pt1,
                  'hep1pt2': hep1pt2,
                  'hep1pt3': hep1pt3,
                  'hep1pt4': hep1pt4,
                  'hep1pt5': hep1pt5,
                  'hep1pa1': hep1pa1,
                  'hep1pa2': hep1pa2,
                  'hep1pa3': hep1pa3,
                  'hep1pa4': hep1pa4,
                  'hep1pa5': hep1pa5,
                  'hep1var': hep1var,
                  'hep1rem': hep1rem
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');
                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#editModalEnroll').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Validation error!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 3000});
                        }, 500);
                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    }
                    else if ((data.msg)) 
                    {
                       $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                      toastr.warning('Record not found! Record might has been deleted earlier or has been altered.', '[HEP] Oops Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        $('.items' + id).remove();
                        $('.form-horizontal').show();
                    }
                    else if (data.exmsg){
                      toastr.warning('Something went wrong.', '[HEP] Oops Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                      $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                    }
                     else {
                        toastr.success('Successfully updated this record!', '[HEP] Success Alert', {timeOut: 10000});
                        $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                    }
                },
                statusCode: {
                401: function() { 
                    window.location.href = 'login'; //or what ever is your login URI 
                  }
                }
            });
          }
        });
    </script>
    @endif
```